# make-standalone-toolchain.sh issue on Mac OS because it already has gcc installed at /usr/bin

Tags: macos, android-ndk, libcurl

I am trying to build libcurl for NDK on MacOS, after I added the toolchain generated by "make-standalone-toolchain.sh" to PATH, it still use the system gcc/ar/... under "/usr/bin". What should I do?

Comment: A good way to compile curl "https://github.com/swisspol/curl-android-ndk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add it to the start of your `$PATH`, not to the end.

That is, you add it like this:

```
export PATH=/your/local/toolchain/bin:$PATH
```

If you add it at the end, it will only search that directory last, after checking all other directories in the path.